# How to compare multiple frequency distributions with some zeroes?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, frequency, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a data frame with frequencies for the teacher profession descriptors as it is perceived by 1st year, 2nd year and MA students. Some of this frequencies are zeroes. What statistical method can I use here to compare these three distributions? Is the Kruskal-Wallis a good method for this particular case?

My data (R code):

```
structure(list(descriptors = c("skills", "responsibility", "pupils", "respect", 
"education", "perseverance", "underpaid", "affection", "knowledge", "education", 
"projects", "hard", "evaluations", "achievements", "exertion", "communication", 
"intellect", "documents"), `1st_year` = c(19L, 6L, 21L, 15L, 12L, 24L, 13L, 10L, 22L, 
13L, 28L, 23L, 21L, 25L, 22L, 21L, 0L, 0L), `2nd_year` = c(18L, 21L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 28L, 
22L, 11L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L), MA = c(12L, 29L, 20L, 21L, 29L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 30L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L)), .Names = c("descriptors", 
"1st_year", "2nd_year", "MA"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: However, the "count" nature of these data seems to be missing a denominator. Are we to believe that these data arise out of a sample of $N_1$ 1st year, $N_2$ 2nd year, and $N_3$ MA students (possibly different numbers) who were assessed in a binary fashion to have certain skills? Are the counts then the numbers of students of each year who were found to have certain positive values? Furthermore, are all students evaluated in equal fashion for all categories? I see the documents section and wonder whether 1st/2nd year students even apply for this evaluation.

Comment: What is the objective of this analysis? That will help you decide how to perform the comparison. As it stands, there are obvious and stark differences among the three distributions, so dwelling on how to formally test this will not be very productive *unless you already formulated specific, testable hypotheses before collecting the data*. Absent such planned comparisons, you will get the most value out of *describing* and *visualizing* these distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Most probability models for counts data account for the fact that there may be 0 counts in the data. Look at Poisson regression, for example, even though these models use a log-link, it's a log-transformation for the predicted rate--not the observations themselves--and for any non-zero Poisson rate there is a non-zero probability of observing 0 counts.

The Kruskal-Wallis does *not* handle this in any predictable fashion. Robustness does not mean panacea. I find the Kruskall Wallis test as a gussied up ANOVA and not all too different from the latter, with a few added complications. If 0s represent truncated values that could in some sense have been below a limit of detection, as with cell counts of a certain pathogen in a collection blood samples, KW may have some applicability.

Comment: @whuber and AdamO Thank you very much for your comments and answers. Now I understand that I have to rethink my data.